# Android equivalence of CSS box shadow

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-layout

I want to create this button considering performance and backward compatibility but I'm struggling to implement the box shadow.

[image]

This is the CSS given by my designing tool (Framer):

```
.round {
  width: 140px;
  height: 40px;
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 30px 0px rgba(20, 122, 255, 0.5);
  background-color: var(--token-589222af-8822-45b2-90c2-ff6f2729b888, #147aff);
  overflow: visible;
  border-radius: 22px;
}
```

Comment: did you find anything?

Comment: Nothing unfortunately! Hoping that Google will someday give us proper shadow settings api. For now we can only use elevation or the terrible gradient hack.